# Как узнать в какой версии ECMAScript появилась та или иная фича? Например метод `Object.entries()`

Tags: javascript

Может быть есть какой-то какой-то сервис чтобы можно было быстро посмотреть.

Comment: А зачем вам это надо знать? Обычно больше интересует, какой браузер\версия поддерживает ту или иную фичу. Есть https://caniuse.com/#

Comment: Всегда можно пройтись по спецификациям и посмотреть

Comment: @Grundy Я ожидал этот комментарий от вас. 

Answer (score 1):

Гуглим `mdn {ключевое слово}`.

Например, `mdn object.entries`. В первой ссылке ищем внизу раздел [`Specifications`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Specifications) или в левом сайдбаре с оглавлением

Comment: К сожалению, ссылки оттуда ведут на текущий черновик спецификации, без указания версии, когда особенность была включена в спецификацию.